# xdotool's type command eating characters

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmonad, xdotool

I'm trying to get xmonad to type a common sequence of characters whenever I hit a simple key combo. One instance of this problem is simply typing my email address.

This is what the configuration file for xmonad looks like for me:

```hs
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Gnome (gnomeConfig)
import XMonad.Util.CustomKeys (customKeys)
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig

main = xmonad $ gnomeConfig {
  keys = customKeys delKeys insKeys,
  logHook = return ()
  }
  where
    -- Remap mod-p to dmenu and mod-[sd] to swapping xinerama screens.
    delKeys :: XConfig l -> [(KeyMask, KeySym)]
    delKeys XConfig { modMask = modMask } =
      [ (modMask, xK_p), (modMask, xK_w), (modMask, xK_e) ]

    insertEmailAddress :: KeyMask -> [((KeyMask, KeySym), X())]
    insertEmailAddress modMask = [ ((noModMask, xK_Menu), spawn "xdotool type thisismyemail@example.com") ]

    insKeys :: XConfig l -> [((KeyMask, KeySym), X())]
    insKeys XConfig { modMask = modMask } = insertEmailAddress modMask
```

However, when I hit my menu key (it's in the bottom right of my keyboard) I get only the last half or so. Like: `yemail@example.com` or `isismyemail@example.com`. It's totally unpredictable where the printing will start.

I have found a workaround by changing the `xdotool` command to `xdotool sleep 0.1 type thisismyemail@example.com`. This seems to work without fail but I have no idea why. Any thoughts?

using xmonad 0.11 & xdotool version 3.20140217.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--sync` option was exactly what I was looking for!

However, the `--sync` option only exists on a particular set of get or search commands.

The solution turned out to be: `xdotool getwindowfocus windowfocus --sync type thisismyemail@example.com`

What's happening here is that we first get the window that is focused, via `getwindowfocus` (`getactivewindow` is an alternative if the other doesn't work).

All we're doing differently is getting the active window and setting it to the same thing. The key difference is the presence of the `--sync` option which forces `xdotool` to wait until the previous command has been applied.

So we guarantee that we're focused to a particular window and will be able to type commands.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to increase the delay between keystrokes using `--delay` (default is 12ms):

```
xdotool type --delay 100 thisismyemail@example.com
```